# Orthogonal family of polynomials from derivative of Legendre polynomials.

Tags: calculus, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

Let $$f_n(x) = \frac{d^4}{dx^4}P_n(x)$$

where $P_n(x)$ are the Legendre polynomials. By which polynomial should one multiply this family to construct a family or orthogonal polynomials on $[-1,1]$ with weight factor $1$?

I have no idea where to start with this. Looking for some hints how to even begin. What theory is relevant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to multiply $f_n$ by $(1-x^2)^2$ to get an orthogonal family of polynomials. In general, if $\{P_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is the system of orthogonal polynomials with respect to the weight $W(x)$ then $k-$ the derivatives form an orthogonal system with respect to the weight $W^k(x)a(x)$ where $b(x)$ comes from the differential equation for orthogonal polynomials:
$$a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'+\lambda_n y=0.$$

In this particular case, Legandre polynomials arise as solutions of the differential equation
$$(1-x^2)y''(x)-2xy'+n(n+1)y=0.$$

and $W=1$ which makes $4- $th derivatives to be orthogonal with respect to the weight $(1-x^2)^4.$ In other words $(1-x^2)^2f_n$ are going to be orthogonal with respect to the weight $1.$

One way to prove the statement above is to use the given differential equation together with integration by parts.

Comment: Maybe some typos."form an orthogonal system with respect to the weight $W^k(x)a(x)$. In the Legendre case $a(x)=1-x^2$, but you write $a^2(x)f_n$.

Comment: @leshik, you write, "One way to prove the statement above is to use the given differential equation together with integration by parts." Can you be more specific? Can you explain further with the given differential equation?